# JS Want to Iterate and set value of each key in a nested object to empty "", and create array of such objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested, iteration, javascript-objects

Base Object :

```
obj = {
    "place": "{{base_gplaceId}}",
    "feedInputs": [
        {
            "subCategoryQuestion": "{{base_gquestionId}}",
            "context": "other",
            "image": "abc.jpg",
            "mediaMetadata": {
                "stickerList": [
                    {
                        "id": "someid2",
                        "sticker": "delish",
                        "weight": 3
                    }
                ],
                "textList": [
                    {
                        "text": "What an evening!!!"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

more keys can have more nesting,

want to set the values of keys = "", one by one and push the updated object to an array

Expected OP :

```
[
{"place":"","feedInputs":[{"subCategoryQuestion":"{{base_gquestionId}}","context":"other","image":"abc.jpg","mediaMetadata":{"stickerList":[{"id":"someid2","sticker":"delish","weight":3}],"textList":[{"text":"Whatanevening!!!"}]}}]},

{"place":"{{base_gplaceId}}","feedInputs":[{"subCategoryQuestion":"","context":"other","image":"abc.jpg","mediaMetadata":{"stickerList":[{"id":"someid2","sticker":"delish","weight":3}],"textList":[{"text":"Whatanevening!!!"}]}}]},

{"place":"{{base_gplaceId}}","feedInputs":[{"subCategoryQuestion":"{{base_gquestionId}}","context":"","image":"abc.jpg","mediaMetadata":{"stickerList":[{"id":"someid2","sticker":"delish","weight":3}],"textList":[{"text":"Whatanevening!!!"}]}}]},

{"place":"{{base_gplaceId}}","feedInputs":[{"subCategoryQuestion":"{{base_gquestionId}}","context":"other","image":"","mediaMetadata":{"stickerList":[{"id":"someid2","sticker":"delish","weight":3}],"textList":[{"text":"Whatanevening!!!"}]}}]},

{"place":"{{base_gplaceId}}","feedInputs":[{"subCategoryQuestion":"{{base_gquestionId}}","context":"other","image":"abc.jpg","mediaMetadata":{"stickerList":[{"id":"","sticker":"delish","weight":3}],"textList":[{"text":"Whatanevening!!!"}]}}]}
,...........]
```

**tried couple of recursions, but not able to break after update inside the nested objects,
any simplistic approach ?**

Comment: Can you try to clarify what you're trying to do exactly? Maybe add a few for examples or details to the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the properties and change the values who are not objects. For having access to the complete object store the root as well and take a copy of the object with stringify and parse for the result set.

```js
function visitAll(object, root = object) {
    return Object
        .keys(object)
        .flatMap(k => {
            if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') return visitAll(object[k], root);
            const value = object[k];
            object[k] = '';
            const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(root));
            object[k] = value;
            return result;
        });
}

var object = { place: "{{base_gplaceId}}", feedInputs: [{ subCategoryQuestion: "{{base_gquestionId}}", context: "other", image: "abc.jpg", mediaMetadata: { stickerList: [{ id: "someid2", sticker: "delish", weight: 3 }], textList: [{ text: "What an evening!!!" }] } }] },
    result = visitAll(object);

result.forEach(o => console.log(JSON.stringify(o)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks That Worked for setting Empty & Null.

Comment: when i try ```delete object[k]``` at ```object[k] = '' ;``` to remove the Property from the object, the final output is deforming totally, 
i end up deleting all the properties and not only one in each output object.